# Kivy automatically adjusting buttons and labels to fit screen

Tags: python, kivy

Hello I need help making my buttons and labels to stay fixed whenever I'm changing the display resolution. I have a video link of what I mean by that.

link: https://youtu.be/GJ3f88ebDqc?t=29s

If anyone could make me a example of code or explain and show me that would be great. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Read kivy documentation about `size_hint` and `pos_hint` in the layouts you are using, and read the documentation about layouts in general.

https://kivy.org/docs/gettingstarted/layouts.html
https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.layout.html

if you are still blocked, post a short code showing what you have in a simple way, and explain what's not behaving how you expect it to.